# Finding the multiplicative inverses in fields

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, inverse

Let's say I have the field $F_{11}$. 
Why does $2$ have the multiplicative inverse $6$?

In some of the examples I have, let's say we are looking $F_5$, why are values up to only $2$ considered? 
So in the example of $F_5$, values $1$, $2$, then $-2$, $-1$ are considered. What about value of $2$ to $5$?
And why do we consider negative values?

The same with $F_{13}$, why are values from $1$ to $6$ considered then $-6$ to $-1$?

Comment: In $F_{11}$ we have $2\times 6=12\equiv 1\mod 11$, that's why $6$ is a multiplicative inverse of $2$.  In $F_5$ we have, say $3\equiv -2\mod 5$ so looking at $-2$ is tantamount to looking at $3$.

Comment: Regarding all the questions except the first one, it probably is because if $x$ is the inverse of $y$, then $y$ is the inverse of $x$.For instances in $\mathbb F_5$, $2\cdot 3=1$, so $2^{-1}=3$ and $3^{-1}=2$.

Comment: As to why one would prefer to look at one complete set of residues rather than another, the usual answer is computational simplicity.  If, say, we wish to compute $10\times 11$ in $F_{13}$ we can certainly multiply them out and find the remainder, but if we note that $10\equiv -3$ and $11\equiv -2$ then we immediately see that $10\times 11\equiv (-3)\times (-2) \equiv 6$